# accept: too many open files issue

Tags: files, ulimit

This happens with geth, when we hit the geth RPC api with a program to get balances for accounts.

First it was failing when the number of files opened by geth was hitting 1024 barrier (the soft limit).  This limit was increased to 4096 in the service file:

```
[Service] 
LimitNOFILE=4096 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/geth --syncmode "fast"
--cache=4096 --rpc --ws --wsorigins '*'  --wsapi "web3,eth,net,rpc"  --datadir "/mnt/eth_volume" 2>/var/log/geth.log Restart=on-failure
```

Now when I see how many open files geth has its up to 30k! This should not be possible.

```
# cat /proc/2833/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             128437               128437               processes 
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files     
Max locked memory         16777216             16777216             bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       128437               128437               signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Also:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
3280354
```

and

```
# lsof | awk '{ print $2; }' | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
 277664 2833
    228 1076
    148 946
    129 1119
    120 1088
    117 948
    114 1
     94 1028
     92 699
     84 932
```

and

```
 ps -ef | grep geth
root      2833     1 19 13:10 ?        00:02:44 /usr/bin/geth --syncmode fast --cache=4096 --rpc --ws --wsorigins * --wsapi web3,eth,net,rpc --datadir /mnt/eth_volume 2>/var/log/geth.log
```

and

```
#  cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2176    0   3280354


# cat /proc/2833/limits | grep files
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
```

Questions:

1. how is it that the geth process is suddenly able to use far more than its soft and hard limits (according to lsof anyway, proc limits shows the "correct" value, but its still breaks)
2. Any ideas how to fix this situation (i.e. stop geth failing with too many open file errors)?

GETH version = 1.8.10-statble

## UPDATE 1

I just tried setting the limit to 32000 (LimitNofile=32000). It still fails, and cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr still gives a number around 2200, and lsof still gives a number around 28,000.